# JMeter JMS samplers not attaching Client SSL certificate (self signed certificate)

Tags: ssl, jmeter, jms

I am running a JMS point to point sampler for TIBCO EMS queue testing. I have added all the tibco ems jars to jmeter lib folder. Configured the queue details, context factory, user credentials in JMS sampler.
When hitting the TIBCO ems with tcp request for queue, it is working. But while hitting with SSL url it is failing to connect.

I tried below way to attach the Self signed certificate given by tibco team

1. added the .pem file (only begin and end certificate) to JAVA JDK cacerts file and opened Jmeter in command line with -Djavax.net.ssl.keystore=cacerts with password. The SSL request failed to connect with tibco ems server
2. extracted the certificate from server through openssl -connect commands, copied the begin & end certificate sections to .cer file and used keytool to add them to trustore. Started jmeter with this truststore. the JMS sampler still failed.

I understand the SSL certificate is not getting attached with JMS sampler when we are running it. Can some one help out with steps to successfully attached the SSL certificate to the JMS request.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0FSB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Configuring EMS over SSL on Application Servers](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/mdm/9.0.0/doc/html/GUID-048E96D8-0F19-4805-80AF-D6C3E0D62E2A.html) I think you need to provide the following [Java System properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.security_protocol=ssl
jsse.providerClass=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
com.tibco.tibjms.ssl.expected_hostname=xxxx
com.tibco.tibjms.ssl.enable_verify_host_name=false
com.tibco.tibjms.ssl.enable_verify_host=false
com.tibco.tibjms.ssl.trusted=/path/to/your/certificate.pem
```

The properties can either be put into *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) or passed via -D command-line arguments like:

```
jmeter -Dcom.tibco.tibjms.naming.security_protocol=ssl -Djsse.providerClass=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2 ....
```

References:

- [Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)
- [TibjmsContext](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/7.0.1-march-2013/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/naming/TibjmsContext.html)
- [TibjmsSSL](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.3.0-february-2012/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/TibjmsSSL.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)